# How to run a Pi camera on Raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu focal?

Tags: 20.04, lts, raspberrypi

I am trying to launch my Pi camera, but keep failing every time.

I have tried to execute the commands `raspistill`, `raspivid` and `picamera`, but they don't seem to work.

Previously, I added `start_x=1` to `config.txt`.

I also cannot find rpi-update package as well.

Comment: _Previously, I added start_x=1 to config.txt_
To clarify, can you give the full path to the file you edited?

Comment: I also tried several options like `start_x=1` in `/boot/firmware/config.txt` without any luck on a clean 20.04 image. I thought it was my camera, so I installed `raspbian` instead and `raspistill` works like a charm. Note that I was using the `arm64` version of Ubuntu 20.04. Any help appreciated.

Comment: is it working for you? I also installed Ubuntu 20.04 and OpenCV and updated config.txt same as you but for some reason camera is not working.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 is not supporting pi camera yet rapinsitll not installed

Comment: Works with `opencv` as mentioned [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/124465/78940) on Ubuntu 21.04 arm64

Answer (score 2):

You do not mention if you're running a 32-bit or 64-bit kernel, but from your problem description I guess your running 64 bit. If you run the `uname -a` command, it'll probably tell that you're running an aarch64 kernel.

The Raspberry camera driver in Ubuntu 20.04LTS is not compatible with a 64 bit kernel, and apparently that is not easy to fix because the camera needs to talk to the GPU using 32-bit pointers. If you must use the camera, you should use a 32 bit version of Ubuntu, which will require a re-install.

The Raspberry PI organisation recommends running Raspbian, so you may as well install that.

I use Ubuntu aarch64 because I have some code that I cannot easily recompile for 32 bit (armhf), so I gave up on the camera for now.